# Systemd: service which does not exist is enabled?

Tags: systemd

I use [instantiated-units](https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/launching/getting-started-with-systemd/#instantiated-units) in systemd.

If I check for the status of a service which does not exist, I get this message:

```
salt:/srv # systemctl status autossh@DOESNOTEXIST
autossh@DOESNOTEXIST.service - Tunnel For DOESNOTEXIST
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/autossh@.service; **enabled**)
      Active: inactive (dead)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/autossh@.service/DOESNOTEXIST
```

Why is it **enabled**?

Comment: Because someone enabled it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton no, it is not enabled. I tried it with several strange names.